# How can I get Google's two-step verification to work?

Tags: google-account, 2-step-verification, authorization

On my Android phone, I can't seem to use my Google Account because I have the 2-step verification enabled. Can I log into Google without disabling the 2-step verification system?

Here is a link to Google's 2-step verification system:
http://googleblog.blogspot.com/2011/02/advanced-sign-in-security-for-your.html

Logging into my Google account is not a problem using the 2-step verification on a standard PC/Laptop, i.e. on a Microsoft/Mac OS, I just can't seem to use the 2-step verification system  on Android 2.2.2.

Comment: Here is the [link](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/1085463?hl=en) to your answer.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The answer is that you have to use a standard computer, log into your google account 2-step verified google account, go to authorise applications and sites, and set up your android device.  Google have said that 2-step verification will not work yet on android, so they have provided this work around for now.

Here is the link where you create a password to authorize your device:
https://accounts.google.com/IssuedAuthSubTokens

They will then give you a password which you can enter into your phone, allowing you to keep 2-step verification enabled.

Comment: You can do this from the browser on your phone if you are patient and don't have a handy desktop.  I activated my account on a new phone while I was still at the mall that way.

Comment: The page seems to have been moved. Go to https://www.google.com/settings/security and click "App passwords: Settings", add name and click "Generate password"

Comment: Thank you so much for this.  I remain flabbergasted that this process was so opaque.  I went down this path on my own but when I got to the drop down list for creating a new mail password for <select device> and Android was not on the list, I was sure it couldn't be the right answer to just fill in the blank and make up my own value for Android.  Thanks for nothing Google!

Answer (score 10):

Good answer, but this was still confusing to me, because it wouldn't let me enter the app-specific password for Google's Play Store.
Final Solution:

1. Create an app-specific password for Google Play at https://accounts.google.com/IssuedAuthSubTokens
   (E.g., name it "Android Phone Play Store").
2. On the phone, add a 2nd Google account (All Settings > Accounts & sync).
3. Launch Google's Play Store.
4. Go to Menu > Accounts.
5. Switch account; then, switch back.
6. When it asks for a password, enter the app-specific password you've created.

Answer (score 2):

Finally I found the answer for this problem. following url has the answer

http://support.google.com/accounts/bin/answer.py?hl=en&ctx=ch_b%2F0%2FSmsAuthConfig&answer=185833

Create a application specific password.

Enter that as password.