# Just enabled 2-factor authentication for gmail, now on my Android phone I get "Sign-in error" to my google account

Tags: sync, gmail, password

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Google's 2-step verification](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/14884/googles-2-step-verification)

As per today's Stackexchange Podcast I took Jeff's advice and enabled 2-factor authentication for my gmail account. However now when my android phone is complaining with a notification in the top bar saying:

> Sign in error for XXXX@gmail.com

I assume this is a failure in my phone trying to sync my account.

Of course I try to enter in my password (unchanged after enabling 2-factor auth) and it fails. Is there something I need to do to get 2-factor authentication to work correctly with my android device? I looked through the gmail app settings and didn't see anything obvious.

Answer (score 5):

Apparently I needed to generate an application-specific password for my Android phone. When logged into google on a web browser, go under "Account Settings". Then Select "Authorizing application & sites". Once there create a new application specific password under "Generate new application-specific password". The password will be displayed once. Enter it into the Android phone's password prompt, and you should be successfully authenticated. You don't need to remember this password, its only intended to be typed in once and "remembered" locally on your phone. Note you can go to the same screen to revoke the credentials you just gave your android phone.

This is covered by this video:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=zMabEyrtPRg

Comment: I can't find any "Account Settings" after I login to google on mobile browser. I'm assuming you're talking about login to google.com (aka search). Can you explain where you find that link? Do you request for desktop version of the webpage?

Comment: @PedroLoureiro I accessed the page through my PC, not through my phone. I suggest watching the full video.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't have audio at that moment. I was trying to use this to resolve another problem but this won't make it. Thanks anyway