# Multiple gmails in Android phone?

Tags: email, gmail, accounts, 2-step-verification

Is it possible have many gmail -accounts in Android phone? I want to have 2nd verification gmail and some non-2nd-verification gmails in the same phone with different security settings -- like `"onion-model"` in networking.

Comment: Did you make an app-specific password within your 2 verification system for gmail, and use that as a password? That is how I have mine setup. Look here: http://support.google.com/accounts/bin/static.py?hl=en&page=guide.cs&guide=1056283&answer=185833&rd=3

Comment: The two-step auth does work, and with multiple accounts, I've got to Google Accounts on my phone both with 2 step auth. Have you seen this previous question: [How can I get Google's two-step verification to work?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/14884)

Comment: @DylanYaga: thank you, Dylan. I got the puzzle cracked, now the question in the title and clarified the question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, you can use multiple accounts -- did you try it?  I use 3.  Add them like any other account through `Settings -> Accounts and sync -> Add account`.

Comment: Please note that this feature is only available in Android 2.0 and forward.