# Can't buy any paid apps on Google Play store, shows "An error occurred. Please try again."

Tags: google-play-store, nexus-7

On my Nexus 7, I keep getting

> An error occurred. Please try again.

Over and over when attempting to buy any *paid* apps on the Google Play store. It works fine for free apps, but always returns this same error when I try to buy a paid app. I've "tried again" a dozen times with the same result.

[image: google play paid purchase click -- an error occurred. please try again]

I checked my Google account and the Nexus 7 shows up as properly attached to my account. It also works OK in Mail, Calendar, and the other bundled Google apps on the device.

I don't understand why I'm getting this error, which tells me *nothing*. I'd like to buy some Android apps for my Nexus 7, but I can't!

Based on one of the comments, I tried buying the same app on the Google Play website, and I get an odd message next to the Nexus 7 (which does show up in the list of devices for me):

> You have not opened the Google Play Store app recently on this device. Please open it and try again.

[image: You have not opened the Google Play Store app recently on this device. Please open it and try again.]

But, but, but I have the Google Play store open *right now* on my device!

Comment: Have you tried purchasing using the web site in your desktop browser? That might reveal a more descriptive (or at least different) error message.

Comment: Do you have Google Wallet setup?  This could cause an odd error.

Comment: It may be some maintenance error, sometimes it has happened to me even with free apps. I recommend to wait an hour or two and try again.

Comment: Any chance you're rooted? Seems like some similar cases of this are solved by installing a different version of the Play Store, but you'd need root to try that ([example](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=25792997&postcount=29853)).

Comment: not rooted, all default, has been consistently happening since I got it for about a week.

Comment: @dan good idea that gives me slightly more info, still no idea what I need to do to fix this!

Comment: Sounds like your N7 isn't able to communicate with Google. This is usually done with C2DM/XMPP by a background process called "Google Services"  and would explain why paid Apps don't work. IIRC gTalk uses the same infrastructure, does it work on the N7? (asking just out of curiosity)

Comment: @Flow IIRC previous versions (2.1?) had an issue that when you weren't logged into talk you couldn't install apps. It *might* be something like this thought I'm not sure what and why.

Comment: @flow Google Talk seems to work fine.. nobody to chat with at the moment but I can set status, type messages to others, etc.

Comment: Can I [joke](http://support.google.com/googleplay/bin/topic.py?hl=en&topic=2453057&parent=2411735&ctx=topic) a bit?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to this [thread](http://code.google.com/p/google-authenticator/issues/detail?id=159) on code.google.com (from April 2012), it seems that one user solved a similar issue after they were advised to turn off 2 step auth to use Google Play:

> I'm having same issue & tech just advised I have to turn off 2 step
>   verification to get into Play.

So I would **disable 2 step auth on the Google account associated with the device** and try again. (If that doesn't work, I wonder if it's even worth trying a factory reset with 2 step auth turned off...)

*BTW: That thread is in the issues list for source code behind the Google Authenticator Application. The issue is not actually related to that application, however, after setting up 2 step auth the user reportedly could not access Google Play so that is why they blamed that app.*

---

Alternatively (still assuming 2 step auth is part of the issue), you could create an app-specific password for Google Play as described in [this answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/22228/15). Quoting that answer:

1. Create an app-specific password for Google Play at https://accounts.google.com/IssuedAuthSubTokens (E.g., name it "Android Phone Play Store").
2. On the phone, add a 2nd Google account (All Settings > Accounts & sync).
3. Launch Google's Play Store.
4. Go to Menu > Accounts.
5. Switch account; then, switch back.
6. When it asks for a password, enter the app-specific password you've created.

Comment: I am definitely using 2-factor auth, so this is possible

Comment: @JeffAtwood did the latter work for you?

Comment: @jrg have not had time to check but seems the most plausible explanation

Comment: I experienced a problem with 2-factor when factory resetting a device (HTC Incredible with Gingerbread). Upon entering Google account info, I would get an error (until I turned off 2-factor auth). So it seems reasonable that 2-factor could cause an issue with the (market) account on a new device.

Answer (score 6):

In order of least to most destructive.

1. clear data on market app, reboot
2. remove your google account, reboot, add it again
3. clear data from google framework services (this is similar to above, in that it will log you out, but I'm not sure what else this clears), reboot, sign back in.

the 3rd one was what finally fixed it for me and I haven't had the issue again.

Comment: excellent! how exactly do I do #3 in your list though? Eldar's answer covers #1, and #2 is pretty simple.

Comment: @JeffAtwood: Look for "Google Framework Services" in the `Settings->Apps` list.

Comment: @eldar well, I went to "Google Framework Services" in apps, cleared data for that app, rebooted the tablet and... same error unfortunately. Going to have to try more stuff.

Answer (score 4):

I recall seeing [a post on RootzWiki](http://rootzwiki.com/topic/28025-google-play-an-error-has-occurred-please-try-again-later/) where someone was seeing a very similar issue, though on a Galaxy Nexus. Specifically, he had the following symptoms:

> To my dismay I found that I get an error no matter what I try to buy. Free apps seem to work fine.

[The solution](http://rootzwiki.com/topic/28025-google-play-an-error-has-occurred-please-try-again-later/#entry747756) he ultimately ended up finding was:

> Got it! Found a tweet from Peter Alfonso stating to uninstall the market updates and clear cache.

To do this, go into `Settings->Apps`, swipe left to the "All" tab, then select the Play Store (it should be titled "Google Play Store" so look in the 'G' area) and press <kbd>Uninstall Updates</kbd>. Once that's finished, hit <kbd>Clear cache</kbd>, or <kbd>Clear data</kbd> if you want to wipe all of its data completely. Once you've done that, relaunch the Play Store and try to purchase the app again.

Comment: this is great, but I don't see any "Uninstall Updates" on the Google Play Store app info page. I see: Clear Data, Clear Cache, Clear Defaults. I'll try clearing cache and data now.

Comment: Done, then rebooted tablet, same error unfortunately.

Comment: @JeffAtwood: It's possible that the N7 ships with the most recent version of Play, then, so there's actually no updates to uninstall.

Answer (score 1):

I just had this problem on my Nexus 7, though error message was Authentication is required. You need to sign into your Google Account, but same symptoms, everything worked fine except for downloading paid apps.

The problem was Google Wallet was disabled. *To protect your data and privacy, your Apps Google Wallet account will be suspended when your account password is reset by your Google Apps administrator.* Which was news to me and the root cause. I had to ring them to renable Wallet, then Google Play started working again for paid apps.

Answer (score 0):

Issue reported on Google:

[[#4319215] Paid apps are not available in territories](http://support.google.com/googleplay/bin/static.py?hl=en&page=known_issues.cs&ki_topic=1319135#ki-2677177)

<sup>Payment and buying apps/in-app items -> [#4319215] Paid apps are not available in territories</sup>

> We’ve received reports that some users living in a territory don’t have access to the same Android apps on Google Play as that territory’s parent country. You may be experiencing this issue if:
>
> - You live in a non-sovereign geographic region or a country subdivision
> - **You’re receiving error messages when trying to purchase Android apps** on Google Play or you don’t see paid apps on Google Play at all (you’re only seeing free apps)
>
> There is no workaround available right now, but we’ll continue to update this page with developments, so check back soon.
>
> Issue first reported on: February 1, 2012
>   Last updated on: July 3, 2012

Are you on a territory? If not, consider [reporting your issue](http://support.google.com/googleplay/bin/request.py?contact_type=contact_policy&policy=apps) at Google Staff.

Comment: I am in the USA, so far as I know, that is not a territory?

Comment: @JeffAtwood Dono.. hence me asking! Don't really understand how the "map" gets divided where you are :) *(Portugal here)*

Comment: @JeffAtwood Here for certain things, like telecommunications, we're divided by territories..